# Custruct proper query: WP_Term_Query with child_of, depth and meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a 'product_cat' query. I have a big category tree, where some of them are having ACF fields (On/Off). I need to query all categories from parent id which have two options set as On.

The query with `'child_of' => '18','depth' => '-1'`, is working. `'meta_query'` with filters too. But when added together it's returning nothing.

```php
$args = [
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'child_of' => '18',
    'depth' => '-1',
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'meta_query' => array(
        [
            'key' => 'product_category',
            'value' => 1
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'is_eco',
            'value' => 1
        ]
    ),
];
$term_query  = new WP_Term_Query( $args);
if (!empty($term_query->terms)) {
    foreach ($term_query->terms as $term) {
         echo $term->name;
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to query all categories/subcategories from parent id 18, with `meta_query` filters?

Answer (score 2):

I am just a beginner, but you should to use after

`'meta_query' => array(" "'relation' => 'OR'` or `'relation' => 'AND'` row.

Comment: The `relation` arg defaults to `OR` in meta queries so it is fine to omit it unless you specifically need to change it to `OR`. 

Of course, being explicit offers an advantage to anyone reading the code.